# How to install a specific version of apache-spark via homebrew?

Tags: macos, apache-spark, homebrew

In the past I had installed `apache-spark` using `homebrew` as follows:

```
brew install apache-spark
```

Until recently that had given me `apache-spark` version `3.3.1`.  Now it gives `3.3.2` that is incompatible with the [azure] servers we use. I need `3.3.1` .

I have tried this:

```
brew install apache-spark@3.3.1
```

But no dice:

```
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.json
##O#-#                                                                        
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.json
##O#-#                                                                        
Warning: No available formula with the name "apache-spark@3.3.1". Did you mean apache-spark?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
apache-spark ✔

To install apache-spark ✔, run:
  brew install apache-spark ✔
```

I also visited the [Homebrew apache-spark page](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/apache-spark#default) that does not provide an alternative:

[image]

So what is the correct process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the commit where the version updated, https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/05b11b92801d68599b225f9cebc56d81f2ac85eb, you will find the previous commit number on line 7 in Red; that hash can be used to install the previous versions:

`curl -L https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/raw/91df3e3f73682d32261a8b245af6b0553dc5cf4af208ef82219283d23ee01ece/Formula/apache-spark.rb -o apache-spark.rb && brew install apache-spark.rb`

**Update**  Version 3.3.1 is now archived, it can be obtained here: [apache-spark 3.3.1](https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.3.1/spark-3.3.1.tgz)

Comment: I would say use this commit, `aa0448b6b83458d5d52b93dd450f7c6dbf750590`, this has bottle references in it, otherwise, you will build from source.

Comment: I wasn’t sure what the difference was so picked the more recent one.

Comment: This `curl` accesses some kind of a download link, so the command as shown does not work. I'll try to do it manually. Update: the link is 404 actually.  I'll look into what the correct commit is now